# self.kill() not removing sprite after Collision between Shot out Bullet and PowerUP

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to shoot out bullets right now and have them collide with a powerup successfully. Right now, I expect to do this because my bullet class has a checkCollision function. I also have called bullet.update in my update class in the GameScreen, so I'm not sure what's happening.

Here is my Bullet class:

```
class Bullet(Image):

    def __init__(self, screen_size, width, height, filename, color = (255, 0, 0)):

        super().__init__(screen_size, width, height, filename, color = (255, 0, 0))

    def checkCollision(self, powerup):

        return pygame.sprite.collide_mask(self, powerup)

    def removeBullet(self, powerup):
        if self.checkCollision(powerup):
            self.kill()

    def update(self, powerup):
        self.rect.centerx += 3
        self.removeBullet(powerup)
```

Here is my PowerUp Class

```
class PowerUp(Image):


    kill_time = 0
    def __init__(self, screen_size, width, height, filename,  color = (255, 0, 0)):

        super().__init__(screen_size, width, height, filename, color = (255, 0 , 0))


        _centerx = random.randint(20, 1100) 
        self.radius = 10
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(_centerx-self.radius,
                                _centery-self.radius,
                                self.radius*2, self.radius*2)

    def update(self):

        pass
```

And here is where I run everything:

```
class GameScreen(SceneBase):

    randomNumber = random.randint(0, 2)
    def __init__(self):
        SceneBase.__init__(self)
        self.bg = pygame.image.load("images/asianbackground.jpg")
        self.my_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 50)

        self.bullets_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.powerup_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player_paddle = classes.PlayerPaddle(screen_size, 40, 100, SceneBase.player1_character, self.bullets_group)

        self.ai_paddle = classes.AIPaddle(screen_size, 40, 100, SceneBase.characterlist[GameScreen.randomNumber])
        self.pong = classes.Pong(screen_size, 20, 20, "images/pokeball.png")

        self.now1 = pygame.time.get_ticks()



    def ProcessInput(self, events, pressed_keys):
        for event in events:
            self.player_paddle.handle_event(event)

    def Update(self):
        self.player_paddle.update() 
        self.ai_paddle.update(self.pong, self.player_paddle) 
        self.pong.update(self.player_paddle, self.ai_paddle)


        # if someone reaches a score of 2, then exit the game 
        if self.player_paddle.score == 2 or self.ai_paddle.score == 2:
            SceneBase.is_game_over = True 
            self.SwitchToScene(GameOverScreen())

        time_difference1 = pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.now1


        current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

        if time_difference1 >= 2000:
            powerup = classes.PowerUp(screen_size, 40, 40, "images/ramen.png")
            powerup.kill_time = current_time + 5000
            self.powerup_group.add(powerup)
            self.now1 = pygame.time.get_ticks()


        current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

        for powerup in self.powerup_group:
            for bullet in self.bullets_group:
                bullet.update(powerup)
            if powerup.kill_time <= current_time:
                self.powerup_group.remove(powerup)



    def Render(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.bg, (0, 0))
        self.bullets_group.draw(screen)
        self.powerup_group.draw(screen)
        self.player_paddle.draw(screen)
        self.ai_paddle.draw(screen)
        self.pong.draw(screen)

        #Make the text for the user 

        player_text = "Player 1" + ":" + str(self.player_paddle.score)
        player_text_image = self.my_font.render(player_text, True, GREEN)
        screen.blit(player_text_image, (screen_size[0] //4, screen_size[1] * 0.8))

        #Make the text for the AI
        ai_text = "Player 2" + ":" + str(self.ai_paddle.score)
        ai_text_image = self.my_font.render(ai_text, True, GREY)
        screen.blit(ai_text_image, (3* screen_size[0] // 4, screen_size[1] * 0.8))

    def SwitchToScene(self, next_scene):
        self.next = next_scene
```

Comment: What is your question, though?

Comment: Right now, when the powerup and bullet collide, nothing is happening though I wrote self.kill()

Comment: did you check if line `self.kill()` is executed ? Maybe your code never runs this line ? Or maybe you get error message. Did you check it ?

Comment: I fixed it! This question is resolved. However, I realized if I endlessly shoot out bullets, the game lags

Answer (score 0):

`Sprite` has list with groups to which he belongs. You have to add `bullet_group` to this list in bullet and then `kill()` will remove bullet from group `bullet_group`

```
elif event.key == pygame.K_u:
  bullet = Bullet(screen_size, 25, 25, "images/naruto.png", color = (255, 0 , 0))
  bullet.rect.centerx = self.rect.centerx
  bullet.rect.centery = self.rect.centery 

  bullet.add(self.bullet_group) # <-- add group to bullet

  self.bullet_group.add(bullet)
```

---

Here bullet which should live only 3 seconds (3000ms).
See `self.lifetime` in `__init__` and `removeBullet`

```
class Bullet(Image):

    def __init__(self, screen_size, width, height, filename, color = (255, 0, 0)):

        super().__init__(screen_size, width, height, filename, color = (255, 0, 0))

        self.lifetime = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 3000

    def checkCollision(self, powerup):

        return pygame.sprite.collide_mask(self, powerup)

    def removeBullet(self, powerup):
        if pygame.time.get_ticks() >= self.lifetime:
            self.kill()
        elif self.checkCollision(powerup):
            self.kill()

    def update(self, powerup):
        self.rect.centerx += 3
        self.removeBullet(powerup)
```